# Pinescipt stop loss at lowest point of previous 10 bars from entry bar

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to set my stop loss at lowest point of previous 10 bars from entry bar but it just doenst work. The red line plotted below is the stop loss level which is definitely not correct.

[Stop loss level example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYaXc.png)
Anyone got any idea :(

```
//@version=4
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD


var float longsl=na

long_entry=crossover(delta, 0)

if (long_entry)
    longsl:=lowest(source=low,length=10)



strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,when=long_entry)
strategy.exit("Long exit","Long",limit=xxxxx,stop=longsl)

plot(strategy.position_size!=0 or long_entry  ? longsl:na,title = "SL",color = color.red,style = plot.style_linebr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted this version 5 and made some small changes. First I took the lowest function out of the local scope and then used an if statement to change the value of your stop loss when a long_entry signal occurs.

```
//@version=5
strategy('MACD Strategy', overlay=true)
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ta.ema(close, fastLength) - ta.ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ta.ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD

sl = ta.lowest(low,10)

var float longsl = na

long_entry = ta.crossover(delta, 0)

if long_entry
    longsl := sl
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)


strategy.exit('Long exit', 'Long', stop=longsl)

plot(strategy.position_size != 0 or long_entry ? longsl : na, title='SL', color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Please accept the answer as correct with the check mark.